# iOS 11 random disconnection with external bluetooth device

Tags: ios, xcode, core-bluetooth, ios11

I use CoreBluetooth framework to connect external bluetooth device, in all iOS don't have random disconnection, but on iOS 11 it disconnect.
Maybe some one has any idea what's wrong with ios 11 and corebluetooth, CBCentralManager?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

My app worked disconnected every 5 minutes on iOS 11.0.x,(I'm sorry for the correct version), But in iOS 10 or eralier version is OK. So I try to change the peripheral deviece, change a Android phone to test, both of them are running OK.

Then I update the version to iOS 11.1.1, And the BUG looks like to be FIXed.

Answer (score 0):

Your bluetooth device is disconnected when your iphone/ipad goes to sleep. This is due to iOS 11 is requiring all application to add background mode to their info.plist. Look at screenshot provided below, add it to your app's info.plist and that will resolve your iOS 11 randomly disconnect issue when device goes to sleep.

[image: iOS 11 bluetooth issue]